# When I shallow the data it comes unordered. Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm facing a problem when I'm trying to get the data shallowed from Firebase Database.
Here is the node that I'm trying to shallow:
[image]

and here is the response after I've called the Rest API:

```
{
"-KzPO6veQ986jxq6jlHK": true,
"-KzQeHwhWQozjb_bqRXl": true,
"-KzPLigBLTL5w8wcSsnA": true,
"-KzPOMEB7C7GawO_7o8b": true,
"-KzVcYwM3IMnaF8DbhOe": true,
"-Kz5XqskF0zLLogT_sl-": true
}
```

You can try yourself by open the following URL: https://librostic-fa290.firebaseio.com/books.json?&shallow=true 
This is not the response that I'm specting because as you can see it is unordered in a weird way.
Am I getting the correct response?

Answer (score 2):

The [REST API Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-ordered-data) explains that query results are unordered:

> The REST API Returns Unsorted Results: JSON interpreters do not
>   enforce any ordering on the result set. While orderBy can be used in
>   combination with startAt, endAt, limitToFirst, or limitToLast to
>   return a subset of the data, the returned results will not be sorted.
>   Therefore, it may be necessary to manually sort the results if
>   ordering is important.